# ASP NET Core Valor dinamico "Route"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, route

Tem como o parametro do route ser dinamico ?? por exemplo eu quero que quando o uf for "sp" eu coloque sao-paulo, e assim por diante com os demais estados. Porque ai quando carregar a aciton ele carrega a url conforme eu informei. O meu problema na verdade é conseguir reescrever a url escondendo os parametros. Se alguem tiver alguma luz eu agradeço.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/sao-paulo")] <<<< (Esse Parametro tem como ser dinamico ????)
    public IActionResult EstadoSelecionado(string uf)
    {
        
        return View("Index_new", pessoa);
    }
```

Comment: se voce passar o valor entre chaves na rota, ela assume o valor do parametro. por exemplo: [Route("/{uf}")]

Comment: @MarcosJunior Simplesmente muito, mas muito obrigado. Me ajudou demais, eu tinha tentado uma vez assim, ams ai fui ler a documentação e esse parâmetro não pode ser null. Cara, forte abraço vlw demais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passando o parametro na rota entre chaves

```
[Route("{uf}")] //uf assumirá o valor para o parâmetro
```

Outro detalhe que você mencionou no comentario para casos em que o valor possa vir null. você pode tratar isso fazendo outro mapeamento para o mesmo método.

exemplo:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("estados")] //se nao houver valor, uf será null
[Route("estados/{uf}")]
public IActionResult EstadoSelecionado(string uf)
{
    
    return View("Index_new", pessoa);
}
```

Perceba que eu adicionei estados a rota para que nao entre em conflito com outras rotas que nao tenham parametros.. se não for o seu caso, você pode adicionar uma rota dessa forma

```
[Route("/")]
```

Comment: Monstro demais ! Me Ajudou muito consegui terminar minha tarefa. Obg de coração!